# Gtk3 Button - Reduce Padding of Internal Label

Tags: python, button, gtk3

I have a Gtk.Button, and I would like to reduce the internal left and right padding inside the button, so the button's *label* is shown with smaller margins on the left and right sides.

I am able to increase the margins using...

```
label = button.get_child()
label.set_margin_start(50)
label.set_margin_end(50)
```

But I am unable to reduce the margins. Setting the margins to zero has no effect...

```
label = button.get_child()
label.set_margin_start(0)
label.set_margin_end(0)
```

I also tried getting the style context, and reading the margin properties...

```
label = button.get_child()
style_context = label.get_style_context()
margin = style_context.get_margin(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL)
print('left   = %s' % margin.left)
print('right  = %s' % margin.right)   
print('top    = %s' % margin.top)   
print('bottom = %s' % margin.bottom)
```

But it is already zero for all sides...

```
left   = 0
right  = 0
top    = 0
bottom = 0
```

How could I reduce the left and right padding of the text *inside* the button?

EDIT: I've added test code below.

---

basic_window.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import gi

gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GLib
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MainWindowHandlers(Gtk.Window):

    def on_window_destroy(self, *args):

        print('Exit')
        GLib.idle_add(Gtk.main_quit)

    def on_clicked_button_1(self, button):

        print('----------------------------------')
        print('Button 1 Clicked')
        print('----------------------------------')

        # Get the child label.
        label = button.get_child()

        # Set the child's margins to 30. They expand.
        label.set_margin_start(20)
        label.set_margin_end(20)

        # Investigate the child's style context.
        style_context = label.get_style_context()
        margin = style_context.get_margin(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL)
        print('left   = %s' % margin.left)
        print('right  = %s' % margin.right)   
        print('top    = %s' % margin.top)   
        print('bottom = %s' % margin.bottom)

        print('----------------------------------')
        print()

    def on_clicked_button_2(self, button):

        print('----------------------------------')
        print('Button 2 Clicked')
        print('----------------------------------')

        # Get the child label.
        label = button.get_child()

        # Set the child's margins to 0.
        # They stay the same size.
        # This does not reduce the left/right padding as I expect.
        label.set_margin_start(0)
        label.set_margin_end(0)

        # Investigate the child's style context.
        style_context = label.get_style_context()
        margin = style_context.get_margin(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL)
        print('left   = %s' % margin.left)
        print('right  = %s' % margin.right)   
        print('top    = %s' % margin.top)   
        print('bottom = %s' % margin.bottom)

        print('----------------------------------')
        print()

try:

    builder = Gtk.Builder.new_from_file('basic_window.ui')

    handlers = MainWindowHandlers()
    builder.connect_signals(handlers)

    window = builder.get_object('window')
    window.show()

    Gtk.main()

except Exception as exception:

    print('Error: %s' % exception)
```

---

basic_window.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="default_width">500</property>
    <property name="default_height">300</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkGrid">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button_2">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Add 20 Pixels</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="halign">center</property>
            <property name="valign">center</property>
            <property name="hexpand">True</property>
            <property name="vexpand">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_clicked_button_1" swapped="no"/>
            <style>
              <class name="suggested-action"/>
            </style>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">0</property>
            <property name="top_attach">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button_1">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">Set to 0 Pixels</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
            <property name="halign">center</property>
            <property name="valign">center</property>
            <property name="hexpand">True</property>
            <property name="vexpand">True</property>
            <signal name="clicked" handler="on_clicked_button_2" swapped="no"/>
            <style>
              <class name="suggested-action"/>
            </style>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="left_attach">0</property>
            <property name="top_attach">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: create minimal working code which we could run and test problem. Maybe problem is not Button but layout manager which may automatically resize widgets to window's size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reduced margin using style `{padding: 0}`

But if there is other button with bigger margin/padding then (in my example)  `Box()` resizes first button to use the same sizes. It may need different layout manager

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Gdk


class ButtonWindow(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)

        screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
        provider = Gtk.CssProvider()
        style_context = Gtk.StyleContext()
        style_context.add_provider_for_screen(screen, provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)
        #provider.load_from_path('app.css')
        #provider.load_from_data("#small {margin: 0; padding: 0;}".encode())
        provider.load_from_data("#small {padding: 0;}".encode())

        hbox = Gtk.Box()
        self.add(hbox)

        button1 = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Padding 0")
        button1.set_name('small') # assign CSS with padding 0
        hbox.pack_start(button1, False, False, 0)

        #button2 = Gtk.Button.new_with_label("Normal padding")
        #hbox.pack_start(button2, True, True, 0)

        #button2.set_name('small') # assign CSS with padding 0

win = ButtonWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

---

`{padding: 0}`

[image]

Second button (with standard padding) is higher and automatically it adds top/bottom padding to first button.

[image]

Both buttons with `{padding: 0}`

[image]